# Viewbag is not having any property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using a `viewbag` to store an int and pass it to another controller but im having trouble in using it in a link. It's always empty and I dont know why.
 What is wrong?

**controller:**

```
public ActionResult PurchaseSelectStock(int? clientID)
{
    ViewBag.id = clientID;

    return View(db.Stock.ToList().Where(x => x.Status == "Deployed"));
}
```

**view:**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Select", "PurchaseDetail", "Stocks", routeValues: new
  { 
    stockID = item.StockID, 
    clientID = ViewBag.id
  }, 
  htmlAttributes: null)
```

Comment: Seeing as your clientID is nullable, are you sure its actually set?

Comment: @Stuart yes i am sure. I checked it

Comment: Just a note, if the Stock comes from the database, do you really want to first `ToList()` and then `Where` it?

Comment: `PurchaseSelectStock` has `[httpGet]` or `[httpPost]`?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen yes

Comment: @AliSoltani neither.

Comment: Is this View code relevant to `PurchaseSelectStock View`?

Comment: @AliSoltani yes. I just found out that the viewbag doesnt have any value.

Comment: Don't you need to explicitly cast the viewbag back to int, so ClientID = (int) Viewbag.Id

Comment: BTW: Why don't you put *.ToList()* to the end of the statement?